# my hadoop cluster, different host use different user, How do I configure slavers?

Tags: hadoop

```
master  host ip:192.168.10.10  user:hadoopm  
slaver  host ip:192.168.10.11  user:slaver1  
slaver  host ip:192.168.10.12  user:slaver2
hadoop  version 1.0
```

How do I configure ？

because namenode  use  start-all.sh  script  ,it  will ssh  to  datanode  use the same username(hadoopm),  but  the  datanode（slaver） has  no  name （hadoopm）， so  it will  start fail.
and  i  must  use  diffrent  username  between  master and  slave。
so  how  do  i  configure ???

Comment: Are you referring to the **/conf/slaves** file?It doesn't contain users, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a user on each node, then all your slaves will share same user.
on debian , [add users](http://linuxg.net/three-tools-for-creating-users-in-debian-based-distros-useradd-adduser-and-newusers/) .